# Find linear SVM feature weights using libsvm

Tags: svm, feature-selection, python, libsvm, software

I'm trying to use linear SVM to do some feature selection. I'm using libsvm, but I cannot figure out how to find feature weights. The model file created looks something like this:

```
svm_type c_svc
kernel_type linear
nr_class 2
total_sv 4006
rho 1.81693
label 1 -1
nr_sv 2004 2002
SV
1 1:0 2:0 3:0 4:0 5:0 6:0 7:0 8:0 9:0 10:0 11:0 12:0 13:0 14:0 15:0 16:0 17:0 18:0 19:0 20:0 21:0 22:0 23:0 24:0 25:0 26:0 27:0 28:147.66667 29:0 30:0 31:0 32:0 33:0 34:0 35:0 36:0 37:0 38:0 39:0 40:0 41:0 42:0 43:0 44:0 45:0 46:0 47:0 48:0 49:0 50:96.666667 51:0 52:0 53:0 54:0 55:0 56:0 57:0 58:0 59:0 60:0 61:0 62:0 63:0 64:0 65:0 66:0 67:0 68:0 69:0 70:0 71:0 72:0 73:0 74:0 75:0 76:0 77:0 78:0 79:0 80:0 81:0 82:0 83:0 84:0 85:0 86:0 87:0 88:0 89:0 90:0 91:0 92:0 93:0 94:0 95:0 96:0 97:0 98:0 99:0 100:0 101:0 102:0 103:0 104:0 105:0 106:0 107:0 108:0 109:0 110:0 111:0 112:0 113:0 114:0 115:0 116:0 117:0 118:0 119:0 120:0 121:0 122:0 123:0 124:0 125:0 126:0 127:0 128:0 129:0 130:0 131:0 132:0 133:0 134:0 135:0 136:0 137:0 138:0 139:0 140:0 141:0 142:0 143:0 144:0 145:0 146:0 147:0 148:0 149:0 150:0 151:0 152:0 153:0 154:0 155:0 156:0 157:0 158:7.5333333 159:0 160:0 161:0 
1 1:0 2:0 3:0 4:0 5:0 6:0 7:0 8:0 9:0 10:0 11:0 12:0 13:0 14:0 15:0 16:0 17:0 18:0 19:0 20:0 21:0 22:0 23:0 24:0 25:0 26:0 27:0 28:145 29:0 30:0 31:0 32:0 33:0 34:0 35:0 36:0 37:0 38:0 39:0 40:0 41:0 42:0 43:0 44:0 45:0 46:0 47:0 48:0 49:0 50:95.5 51:0 52:0 53:0 54:0 55:0 56:0 57:0 58:0 59:0 60:0 61:0 62:0 63:0 64:0 65:0 66:0 67:0 68:0 69:0 70:0 71:0 72:0 73:0 74:0 75:0 76:0 77:0 78:0 79:0 80:0 81:0 82:0 83:0 84:0 85:0 86:0 87:0 88:0 89:0 90:0 91:0 92:0 93:0 94:0 95:0 96:0 97:0 98:0 99:0 100:0 101:0 102:0 103:0 104:0 105:0 106:0 107:0 108:0 109:0 110:0 111:0 112:0 113:0 114:0 115:0 116:0 117:0 118:0 119:0 120:0 121:0 122:0 123:0 124:0 125:0 126:0 127:0 128:0 129:0 130:0 131:0 132:0 133:0 134:0 135:0 136:0 137:0 138:0 139:0 140:0 141:0 142:0 143:0 144:0 145:0 146:0 147:0 148:0 149:0 150:0 151:0 152:0 153:0 154:0 155:0 156:0 157:0 158:2.5 159:0 160:0 161:0
```

And there is more stuff like the last 2 lines.

Commands using either the libsvm original interface or the python interface would be greatly appreciated, as well as any explanation of this model file.

Comment: Could you clarify what you mean by feature weights? Linear SVMs are not a GLM. The support vectors at the bottom of the file are points that approximately "shatter" the decision boundary.

Comment: You can construct the weight vectors from the support vectors and their coefficients. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10131385/matlab-libsvm-how-to-find-the-w-coefficients